# How to check if a class in an OSGi bundle has been correctly unloaded?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, osgi, classloader

I have an application which I suspect to leak some class references.

To expose that buggy behaviour, we wrote a test : [BundleUnloadIT](https://github.com/Riduidel/wisdom-jcr/blob/9ac9d9d9995b4055e586d0073af8e9de53cbe009/jcr-test/src/test/java/org/wisdom/jcrom/BundleUnloadIT.java)

In that test, I use

```
    Assertions.assertThat(weakReference.isEnqueued())
        .as("weak reference should have been enqueued, but is not").isTrue();
```

To test if my reference is correctly gc'ed.
But whatever I try to do, the reference is never enqueued.
So I suspect some reference to that class is leaking somewhere.

So ... am I using the right method to test my class is unloaded ?

And if not, how can I properly do that test ?

And if it is, there is a reference leaked somewhere. how can I find it ?

Comment: *"But whatever I try to do, the reference is never enqueued"*, well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class can only be unloaded (garbage collected) if the class' class loader is not strongly referenced (that is, the class' class loader can also be garbage collected). And a class loader can only be garbage collected if all of the classes it loaded are not strongly referenced. So it is an all-or-nothing proposition. Each class has a strong reference to its class loader and each class loader has strong references to all the classes it has loaded. So it is not possible for a class to be garbage collected if any class loaded by the class loader is strongly referenced.

Comment: OK, but isn't it what I do when I call `osgi.uninstall(bundle);` ? Because, when I look at that test, it seems to me that I maintain no strong reference to the Class object (well, excepted for the one I'm expecting this test to expose).

Comment: `bundle.uninstall` in OSGi doesn't force any classes to unload, because there is no way to do that in the JVM. It sends a stop signal to the bundle, and the bundle implementation is *supposed* to clean up anything it is doing. But a poorly implemented bundle can still hang on to references and prevent garbage collection. A common cause (but not the only cause) for this is when a bundle starts a thread but fails to properly terminate that thread when the stop signal occurs.

Comment: @NeilBartlett ok, in our case, the bundle starts no thread, and bundles are managed by Apache Felix. So ... What is supposed to happen ? Is the class object supposed to be permanent and never GC'ed ?

Comment: @Riduidel No it's not. Sorry I can't tell you what's happening without a lot more data. Bear in mind that the GC is not exactly a predictable beast, it may have simply decided that it doesn't need to clean your class because of a lack of memory pressure.

Comment: @Riduidel I had the same issue. I implemented a "dynamic" bundles install/unistall procedure. In my case, the only way I found to be sure that all new classes are loaded (including classes with same name, in the same package, as the previous loaded ones) was to restart Apache Felix.